# For...in statement Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, for-in-loop

I am studying Objective-C and I came across this "for...in" statement. I searched for it but i still don't get how it works. Could someone explain to me in a noob-friendly how this statement works?

Comment: You mean behind the scenes, or how you use it?

Comment: You can find lots if you search for "fast enumeration objective c"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See [fast enumeration documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html).

Basically you'd have, usually, an array, and you can obtain each item in the array with a handy loop instead of using NSEnumerator or an integer count variable. It makes your code much cleaner to ask for each NSString in your array rather than to have to assign to a variable using `objectAtIndex` for each pass of your loop.

Compare:

```
for (NSString *string in myArray)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *string = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Besides being cleaner, it's also faster. There's a reason this is also called "fast enumeration".

Comment: Faster, safer, more fun... OK, maybe not the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still don't understand what's the particular function of the "string" part. If I had other objects in the array besides strings how would this work? Would it still enumerate through all the objects or would it skip stuff that is not a string?

Comment: You can set the type as id instead, and check for the class of it inside the loop, if you think the array might contain multiple types of object.