# For Looping through Property in an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm trying to loop through my array called `songs` which contains a list of the user's songs from their iPod library, but to get the title, I need to do this (to get an `NSString` of the song titles):

```
[[songs objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
```

I'm trying to create an index of the tableView, but I'm stuck at this bit:

```
for (NSString *title = MPMediaItemPropertyTitle in songs)
{
    rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
    if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
    {
        [rowContainer addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
    }
}
```

Where I get an error

> -[MPConcreteMediaItem substringToIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

On this line: `rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];`.

How do I loop through songs to get the MPMediaItemPropertyTitle and then get the first letter of the song title?  I thought what I am doing is declaring the NSString '`title` and looping through all the titles in songs.  Clearly I'm not :S.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://innofied.com/indexed-list-in-ios/).  Could anybody help me out, please?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a warning for this code... What is the declaration for `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`?

Comment: You've got the Objective-C `for . . . in` syntax wrong - have a look athttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476541/for-in-statement-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..in` loops through the objects in the `songs` array. It won't send a `valueForProperty` message automatically, so you'll have to do that yourself:

```
for (MPMediaItem *song in songs)
{
    NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet
    if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
    {
        [rowContainer addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to do that!  I tried a million ways to sort through the Titles outside of the for loop.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
for (NSString *title = MPMediaItemPropertyTitle in songs)
```

Should be...

```
for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
    NSString *title = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
}
```

Your original code was pointing your `title` reference at an `MPConcreteMediaItem` item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (NSString *title in songs)
   {
     rowTitle= [title substringToIndex:1];  //modifying the statement to its first alphabet

       if ([rowTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitle])  //checking if modified statement is same as section title
             {
                [rowContainer addObject:title];  //adding the row contents of a particular section in array
              }
            }
```