# iOS - get text value from array of UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, textfield

I'm trying to compare the text value from an object of an array, which is a UITextField, with a string. 
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
for (int stunde = 1; stunde <= 11; stunde++) {
    if ([textEingabe[stunde - 1] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //NSLog(@"ignorierem");
        //ignorieren
    } else ....
```

while my array contains:

```
NSArray *textEingabe = @[_texteingabe1.text,_texteingabe2.text,...];
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how do i get the text value of the object from the array? thx

Comment: in objective-c you'd use fast enumeration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7476675/1672895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for-in loop seems the easiest if the goal is just to compare an array of strings to see if they are empty:

```
for(NSString * text in textEingabe){
   if( [text isEqualToString:@""] ){
      //something
   }
   else{
      //something else
   }
}
```