# Looping over an NSmutatable Array starting from a certain index

Tags: objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray

I have a quick question how can I loop over an NSMutable array starting from a certain index. 
For Example I have these double loops I want k to start from the same index as l.

```
for (Line *l in L)
    {
        for (Line *k in L)
        {
............
        }
    }
```

To elaborate further, lets say L has 10 object so l start from 0-10 and k from 0 -10. What I want is if l is equal 1 k should start from 1-10 rather than 0 - 10 and when l is equal 2 k should start from 2- 10 rather than 0. Any help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to modify for-statement.

```
 NSInteger indexYouNeed;
 NSInteger iterationCount;

 for (int i = indexYouNeed; i < iterationCount; i++) {
       /* Your code here */         
  }
```

You may find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476541/for-in-statement-objective-c) helpfulll.

Comment: Do not use `int`. Use `NSInteger`. That matches the data type used by `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is an extension of C, lookup the C `for` loop and you'll have your answer. HTH

**Addendum**

I was going to let you benefit from the learning experience of looking up the C `for` yourself, however at the time of writing all other answers since added give the code but it is not complete, so here is what you need to produce the `l` and `k` values in the order you wish:

```
for(NSInteger lIndex = 0; lIndex < L.count; lIndex++)
{
   Line *l = L[lIndex]; // index into your array to get the element
   for(NSInteger kIndex = lIndex; kIndex < L.count; kIndex++)
   {
      Line *k = L[kIndex];
      // process your l and k
   }
}
```

As you can see the `for` has three sub-parts which are the *initialisation*, *condition*, and *increment*. The *initialisation* is performed first, then the *condition* to determine whether to execute the `for` body, and the *increment* is executed after the statements in the body and before the *condition* is tested to determine if another iteration should be performed. A `for` loop is roughly (there are some differences that are unimportant here) to the `while` loop:

```
initialisation;
while(condition)
{
    body statements;
    increment;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an indexed (ordinary) `for` loop instead of fast enumeration (`for-in`):

```
int l;
for (l=startValue; l<=endValue; l++)
{
    int i;
    for (int i=l; i<=endValue; i++) 
    {
      …
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `int`. Use `NSInteger`. That matches the data type used by `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thanks for the help